# Access to the windows registry using ADO .Net

Tags: .net, ado.net, registry, provider

Exist any ADO.NET Provider for access to the windows registry?  Or rather you can use ADO to connect to the windows registry?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a provider to the registry, but if you're looking to search the registry you could write a recursive function that enumerates the registry keys and applies your search criteria through string comparisons.